# Definition of infinite cyclic subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, free-groups

Let $B$ be a subset of an (additive) abelian group $F$. Then $F$ is free
abelian with basis $B$ iff the cyclic subgroup $\langle b \rangle$ is infinite cyclic for each $b \in B$ and $F = \sum_{b \in B} \langle b \rangle$.

What does it mean for $\langle b \rangle$ to be infinite cyclic?  What's the exact definition?

Comment: Not following.  An infinite cyclic subgroup is a subgroup isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb Z$.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: An infinite cyclic subgroup is a subgroup which is both cyclic and infinite. As lulu says that means it's isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$. Are you aiming to prove that if $b$ is an element of a basis of a free Abelian group, then $b$ generates an infinite cyclic subgroup? It's not clear to me what you actually are asking.

Comment: To stress:  there are free abelian groups that are not cyclic.  For example $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$.  That's the free abelian group on two letters (which, if you like, you may take to be $(1,0),(0,1)$).

Comment: I re-worded the question to ask explicitly what I don't understand.  Which is:  What is the exact definition of a subgroup of a free abelian group that is infinite cyclic?

Comment: The notation $\langle b \rangle$ means $\{ n b : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$ Here, for positive $n,$, $nb$ denotes $ b + b +\ldots + b$ ( with $n$ summands) and for negative $n$, $nb$ denotes $ -b + -b +\ldots + -b$ ( with $-n$ summands). The fact that $\langle b \rangle$ is infinite cyclic means that whenever $n \neq m \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $nb \neq mb.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A group $G$ is *cyclic* if there exists an element $g_0 \in G$ such that every element of $G$ can be written as a power (positive or negative) of $g_0$. An infinite cyclic group is just what it sounds like: a cyclic group that's infinite. This can be equivalently characterized as follows: a cyclic group $G$ is infinite iff no element of $G$ (besides the identity) has finite order.

It's worth noting a few facts about $G$.

1. There exists a canonical projection $\pi : \mathbb{Z} \to G$ for every cyclic $G$, where $\pi(1) = g_0$. The projection is injective iff $G$ is infinite, so the corollary is that the only infinite cyclic group is $\mathbb{Z}$.
2. If $G, H$ are cyclic groups and $|G| = |H|$, then $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic (consider the isomorphism $f(g_0) = h_0$). Combined with the previous fact, this means that cyclic groups are characterized completely by their order.
3. Every subgroup of a cyclic group is also cyclic.
4. Any group $\left< b \right>$ is cyclic by definition.

Now we can identify several equivalent conditions to "$\left< b \right>$ is infinite cyclic".

I) $\left< b \right>$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

II) The map $f : \left< b \right> \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(b^n) = n$ is well-defined (i.e. if $b^n = b^m$, then $n = m$).

III) There exists an onto homomorphism $\left< b \right> \to \mathbb{Z}$.

IV) There exists an imbedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\left< b \right>$.

V) There exist infinitely many imbeddings of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\left< b \right>$ (note that $f(n) = b^{na}$ is a homomorphism for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$).

VI) $\left< b \right>$ is infinite.

You could go on, but there are many ways to check that your cyclic group is infinite.